# Extract numbers with specific pattern from String in Java

Tags: java

I have a string like this

`<li class="number">206-861-1109</li>206-861-1365</li>er">206-861-4532</l`

I want to extract all numbers in this pattern - `206-861-****`

So the output should be

206-861-1109

206-861-1365

206-861-4532

How can i do so? Is it possible through regular expressions? If yes then how?

Comment: `li` doesn't match in your example

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `206-861-\d{4}`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("206-861-\\d{4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<li class=\"number\">206-861-1109</li>206-861-1365</li>er\">206-861-4532</l");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

output:

```
206-861-1109
206-861-1365
206-861-4532
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be as following:

```
String str = "<li class=\"number\">206-861-1109</li>206-861-1365</li>er\">206-861-4532</l";
// or \\d could be used instead of [0-9] 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("206-861-[0-9]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group() + " ");
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use `\d` for `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Zabuza Thanks for note. I added this as a comment